# Setting timers in Quiz apps

Tags: javascript, php, server, client, client-server

I am working on a client-server application where a user logs in and has the option to play and answer questions. The user can answer as many questions as he can in 60 seconds. So, basically, I need to keep track of the timer. There are two approaches; one approach is to start and end the timer on the client and the other is to do it on the server. My questions are:

1. If we do it on the client, then the user can somehow hack it. Also, what if the internet connection breaks? How can I handle that?
2. If we do it on the server, then would it be right as far as performance is concerned? What if there are millions of people playing at the same time? The server would have to keep track of every users' timer and use sockets to notify them. Again what happens if the internet connection is lost? The server while sending message to all the socket channels would also have to keep track if it has received a feedback or not, if not, the server would have to retry sending the timeout message

What would be the appropriate approach here?

Comment: Timer on browser

Comment: you are probably going to need to track the time on both the client side and server side. client side for the U/X portion of the app, and the server side to enforce the integrity of the timer. For connectivity issues, you can take a look as `Service Worker` though I don't know if there will be a way to enforce the integrity of the quiz. Technically speaking, the quiz was not submitted to the server in the allowed duration and there would be little way to prove the submit time wasn't tampered with.

Comment: Thankyou @dgeare. I think you're right. I would also look into Service Worker concept to see how it can be used in my game

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript for the timer as soon as your question page appears a timer function is called which will work for 60 sec

Comment: Simple and sweet solution. Thanks